# Sorting based on upcoming birthday

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building a simple birthday reminder app where I get the names and birthdays in JSON and I need to display the names sorted based on whose birthday is coming next.

My logical thought would be to get the current day and month subtract that from the birthday and then do some kind of sort. But then how would do I handle -ve results or situations like when we are in Dec etc. I was guessing there might have been an simpler solution, but I'm quite clueless.

Here is a plunkr with the base working code: http://plnkr.co/edit/AkP6FRRG917TDdTtfWM7?p=preview

Comment: Convert the current date and birthdate to long values and compare them based on the differences between these two values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others suggested, convert the string to a unix timestamp or date.

Here's an [updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Pntb20MwWPu1yFgc6JTx?p=preview).

The controller adds a fromNow variable to the data:

```
$scope.friends.forEach(function(data){
      var day = data.birthday.split("/")
      var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
      var birthdayDate = new Date(currentYear, day[0] - 1, day[1])
      var now = new Date().valueOf();
      if (birthdayDate.valueOf() < now){ 
          birthdayDate.setFullYear(currentYear+1)
      }
      data.fromNow = birthdayDate.valueOf() - now;
})
```

1. Get the individual date/month parts (so we get a list like ["02","14","1985"])
2. Create a date object based on the current year, the month `day[0]` and the day `day[1]`. (Note we subtract 1 from the months because months are 0-based in in Javascript).
3. Get a numeric value for the current date/time
4. If the birthday is in the past add one year
5. Assign the number of milliseconds between now and the birthday to `fromNow`

You'd need to modify it so that if someone's birthday is today it doesn't add a year, thus placing it last in the list.

Also note I've added quotes to the orderBy parameter:

```
<tr ng-repeat="friend in friends| orderBy:'fromNow' ">
```

Comment: Just perfect, exactly what I was looking for thanks a ton.. the logic for #4 was is so much easier than what I was trying to do :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would go about this by converting the dates to unix timestamps (int values) and doing a simple sort on them.

Convert date to timestamp using javascript [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate%2Fparse)

Answer (score 0):

Convert the current date and birthdate to UNIX time and compare them based on the differences between these two values

```
birthdates = [new Date(1988,01,27), new Date(2013,01,01)];

birthdates.sort(function(firstDate,secondDate){

    //calculate the difference between first date and current date
    firstDifference = new Date() - firstDate;

    //calculate difference between second date and current date.
    secondDifference = new Date() - secondDate;

    //return the smallest value.
    return firstDifference - secondDifference;

});
//display the sorted array.
alert(birthdates);
```